# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string. Can anyone help me

Tags: python-3.x

```
GIRL_GROUPS = ("f(x), SNSD, RED_VELVET, ITZY, MISS_A, WONDER_GIRLS")
print ("%s %s %s %s %s %s" % (GIRL_GROUPS))
```

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The argument tuple contains only one string, `f(x), SNSD, RED_VELVET, ITZY, MISS_A, WONDER_GIRLS`, when it should contain `f(x)`, `SNSD`, `RED_VELVET`, `ITZY`, `MISS_A` and `WONDER_GIRLS`. So, you need quotes around each individual string in the list.

Answer (score 0):

in variable GIRL_GROUPS you have a one string surrounded by parenthesis. you need to convert it into list using `split()` method and use unpack operator(`*`) to unpack values

In order to create a new Tuple, with one expression as an initializer, you need to add a ',' after it:

```
print('%d %d' % (*lst,))
```

Note: unless a is a generator, in this particular situation you could just type:

```
print('%d %d' % lst)
```

your code:

```
GIRL_GROUPS = ("f(x), SNSD, RED_VELVET, ITZY, MISS_A, WONDER_GIRLS")
print ("%s %s %s %s %s %s" % (*GIRL_GROUPS.split(","),))
```

output:

```
f(x)  SNSD  RED_VELVET  ITZY  MISS_A  WONDER_GIRLS
```